# ignite V2.7.0 question about ignite TransactionManager

Tags: ignite

ignite V2.7.0, in the one ignite transaction first query data by objetc ID, then modify the data saved and then query data by objetc ID, but the Data is old?

see the test code:

Comment: //IgniteTransactions start
    //step1: query data by id 1
            select amount from accountWalletAssetMem a where id  = 1;
    // Query results is 10000;
    //setp2: update amount by id 1, add amount from 10000 to 20000;
            update accountWalletAssetMem set amount = 20000 where id = 1;
    //setp3: Second query data by id  1
            select amount from accountWalletAssetMem a where id  = 1;
     // Second Query results still is 10000;
     // my question: why Second Query results still is 10000？ Not 20000?/
/IgniteTransactions stop

Comment: @Bean("igniteTransactionManager")
    @DependsOn("igniteInstance")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "ignite.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public PlatformTransactionManager igniteTransactionManager(IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration)
    {
        SpringTransactionManager transactionManager = new SpringTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setIgniteInstanceName(igniteConfiguration.getIgniteInstanceName());
        return transactionManager;
    }

Comment: @Override
    @Transactional(value = "igniteTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void assetHander(AssetInfo assetInfo) throws BusinessException
    {

Comment: Please don't add code in comments; it's unreadable. [Edit] your question instead and add your code there. Make sure it's formatted as code (indent 4 spaces or use the `{}` button). Make sure you add the code you have to solve the problem (not just test code), and describe exactly what problem you have. Good luck!

Comment: Please ask your question properly.  Take help from here. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)